# Use large key size for RC4 to avoid RC4 bias

Tags: cryptanalysis, stream-cipher, key-size, rc4, key-schedule

I saw a question on StackOverflow where RC4 was initialized by a 1024 bit key (with 2048 the maximum key size, if I'm not mistaken).

Will such a large key size possibly solve any of the bias of the initial bits of the key stream produced by RC4? Does it increase security any other way - other than brute force?

Is there any reason for keys larger than 256 bits for a combined key + IV?

Comment: related [RC4 Keylength Limits](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/3137/18298), [RC2, RC4, RC5 key length](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9963/18298), and [Is RC4 secure with a single-use 32-byte random key prefix and 3072 prefix bytes discarded?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59522/18298), and Just Say No to RC4, kids! by Squeamish Ossifrage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will such a large key size possibly solve any of the bias of the initial bits of the key stream produced by RC4?

There is a bias in the RC4 output at small multiples of the key size; hence a 16 byte key will have biases at offsets 16, 32, 48, etc (with the bias rapidly growing smaller as the offset grows).  This bias happens less often with larger key sizes.

Other than that specific bias, no, increasing the key size doesn't help.

> Is there any reason for keys larger than 256 bits

Actually, I'm not sure if there's any reason to use RC4 at all...

Comment: Yeah, RC4 should be avoided (and Spritz can also be distinguished from random and doesn't bring any benefit other than drop-in RC4 compatibility). I was just being curious.